# Objective-C, how to define a handler for button press?

Tags: objective-c, events, button

I'm a C++ and Javascript developer who is learning objective-c to be a hobbyist cocoa/objective-c programmer for mainly Mac OSX desktop applications. I'm pretty green when it comes to objective-c/cocoa, and I was wondering how I can add a button to my main view and bind a custom handler to that button when it's clicked? What's the best way to do this? I've done this many times with wxWidgets, but this is my first cocoa application to help me learn and get my feet wet.

I would also appreciate any book suggestions or learning resources that you could point me to.

Thanks!

Comment: Get this book, stat: http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619

Comment: @quixoto That looks awesome!! I'm getting it right now. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Don't hit the order button just yet! Add [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1293387243&sr=1-1) before you do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex, I would highly recommend you check out some books before you dive into Objective-C. Coming from C++ and Javascript, you're going to have to better adapt your mindset to what you are going to learn, and if you don't prepare yourself, you're going to be very, very confused. As `quixoto` said, definitely take a look at Aaron Hillegass' [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619), as it will walk you through the process of creating applications and using Xcode and Interface Builder. Before that, however, I would highly recommend you check out Stephen Kochan's [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157), to get a primer on the language and its concepts (although C++ and Objective-C are supersets of C, they are both quite different).

Comment: And objective-c++? I guess the problem is that there's a lot more emphasis on- and offline on objective-c.

Comment: +1, Thanks. This answers my question. I'll grab both those books and dive in! Thanks!

Comment: @Yar You're totally right, though there don't seem to be that many resources for Objective-C++. At first glance, I've found Apple's [Using C++ with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1), and an interesting bit on Wikipedia that [contrasts Objective-C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Philosophical_differences_between_Objective-C_and_C.2B.2B), both interesting things to look into.

Comment: interesting. Personally, I try to do everything in Objective-C (or at least as much stuff as Cocoa does, which mostly related to not using NSNumber much) until proven otherwise. If I need to dive down, I could only use C (since I use .m's), but its correctness would be questionable. Works so far...

Comment: C++ is NOT a superset of C - its an object oriented language based on C. A superset supports all the functionality and syntax of the original language, which C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Farhad Yes, you're right, it's not a *strict* superset of C, but for the most part, they're very compatible. Isn't that a bit nitpicky, though? That wasn't really the point of my answer. (For those reading at home, Wikipedia offers a pretty good reference on the [compatibility between C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)).

Comment: @ItaiFerber Your right, they are very similar. I am sorry if it appeared that I was being nitpicky; you gave a valid answer, so I upvoted it. I just added the comment for clarification for the OP.

Comment: @Farhad No worries, mate. I'm sure you're looking to help. :)